# Concurrency access with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I m developing a SignalR application that communicates with a database. I manage the database using Entity Framework 6.

I'd like to implement a scheduled task, who will be deleting some records in a given table.

The problem is that this task is not running on the main thread of my application. So, if this task removes a record while the main thread is trying to read the same record, the application crashes.

I m managing the database context this way: `using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
//code to get and remove record...
dbContext.saveChanges();`

Which would be the best solution to avoid concurrency problems ? Should I force the scheduled task to run on the main thread ? If yes, how can I do this ? Or should I use transactions locks using the `TransactionScope` class ?

**EDIT**

Scenario: 500ms between each task execution

**execution 1** task called for the first time => **new dbContext instance** => get record => delete record => **saveChanges**...

In the meantime, task is called again.

**execution 2** task called for the second time => **new dbContext instance** (as the first task is still running, two dbContext objects are alive) => get record => delete record => **saveChanges crashes because it has already done the same at the first time.**

Exception: `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

Thanks

Comment: `So, if this task removes a record while the main thread is trying to read the same record, the application crashes.` I'd start there. The application shouldn't crash when there's concurrent access *to a database*. Why does it crash? `SaveChanges` *does* wrap the operations in a transaction, so there's no need for `TransactionScope`, really. The best way to avoid concurrency problems is to manage your dependencies correctly - there's no way to give you a simple 1-2-3 task list to achieve this. Also, using "scheduling threads" is a terrible idea in a ASP.NET application.

Comment: This is too broad. You are basically asking about concurrency strategies in general. There are many solutions and I'm not sure you are familiar enough with the concepts to understand a good answer. I think you need to to some searching on this topic first and ask more concretely, should that be necessary.